# Determinism vs Indeterminism debate

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, determinism

I need to find an article/website/book which offers a brief survey of the dispute determinism vs indeterminism (with no or really few references to the free-will problem). I need them for a high school thesis on deterministic chaos with references to multiple subjects (that is, literature and philosophy).

Comment: I am also interested in reading a book about this debate just out of personal curiosity, although I am tending towards the deterministic dogma

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy [article on Causal Determinism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/determinism-causal/)?